# Your home page and the question therein

Tags: discussion

Why does your home page feature the question, "What is Unity?" and then not provide an actual answer? Is the answer hidden? On another page? Another website? Another server? Another planet?

Comment: Hmmm ... there isn't enough information here.  To whom are you writing, and about which webpage?  Any chance it's Sam Sraury at http://culturedigitally.org/2011/11/ubuntu-unity-and-identity-how-governance-and-lack-of-consensus-affects-cultural-production/

Answer (score 6):

I think you may be slightly confused about what this site is. It's a community driven [question and answer site](https://askubuntu.com/faq)! Questions on the homepage are recently asked and updated questions - if a question doesn't have an answer yet, it's because no one has gotten a chance to answer it! If you can supply an answer or a solution, then feel free to provide one an help out!